# Angular material - issues with tooltip and flex

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

The issue is that my tooltip is shown on the bottom left part of my button when I hover on the botton for the first time. Then it seems it fixes its position and works as expected. This happens in all desktop browsers. I am using v0.9.8.

[image: Sample image]

I have used that example
https://material.angularjs.org/0.9.8/#/demo/material.components.tooltip

Here is the html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/angular-material.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/material-design-iconic-font.css" />
</head>

<body layout="column" ng-app="myApp">
    <md-toolbar class="md-accent">
        <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <span flex="">Awesome Md App</span>
            <md-button class="md-fab md-accent" aria-label="refresh">
                <md-tooltip>
                    Refresh
                </md-tooltip>
                <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_refresh_24px.svg" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;">
                </md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </h2>
    </md-toolbar>

    <div flex layout="row">
        <!--main content-->
    </div>
</body>

<!-- vendor -->
<script src="assets/javascript/vendor/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/javascript/vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="assets/javascript/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="assets/javascript/vendor/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="assets/javascript/vendor/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="assets/javascript/vendor/angular-material.js"></script>

</html>
```

If I remove the flex attribute

```html
<span flex="">Awesome Md App</span>
```

The controls are disordered but the tooltip appears just fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: You should post your entire HTML (head+body). It may be something related to the parent of "md-toolbar".

Comment: Have you include all the css and script files that you need? Did you include _ngMaterial_ in your module?

Comment: Yes, I have included all the css and script files that I need. As I said the problem appears after I refresh the page and hover over the button, on the second hover it all works fine.

Comment: I posted the entire HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove layout="column" from yr body tag.

```
   <body layout="column" ng-app="myApp">

   <body ng-app="myApp">
```

you should place yr main content inside md-content & then give layout="column" or "row" as required.

```
 <md-content flex layout="column">
   <!--main content-->
   <span>above</span>
   <span>below</span>
 </md-content>
```

or

```
 <md-content flex layout="row">
   <!--main content-->
   <span flex>i'm left</span>
   <span flex>i'm right</span>
 </md-content>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! But I need layout="column" in my body, otherwise all my main layout will be broken. Is there anyway that I can modify the tooltip behavior only?